# Cериализация членов статического класса

Tags: c#, классы, сериализация, десериализация, статические-члены

Есть статический класс WorkingClass,включающий в себя массив экземпляров класса Book(не статичного) и методы для сериализации\десериализации

```
    public static class WorkingClass
{
    public static List<Book> books = new List<Book> { };

        public static void Serialize()
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Library\data.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.Write);
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(fs, WorkingClass.books);
            fs.Close();
        }
        public static void Deserialize()
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Library\data.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            WorkingClass.books.Add((Book) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fs));
            fs.Close();
        }
}
```

При закрытии программы вызываем Serialize(),при открытии Deserialize(),чтобы заполнить массив "books" и получаем ошибку

System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Library_App.Book]" к типу "Library_App.Book"."

В чём проблема?

Comment: попробуйте так `WorkingClass.books = (List<Book>) binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fs);`

Comment: @Спасибо,проблема решена)

Comment: @Ruslan_K достойно ответа, я б плюсанул :)

Comment: @Ruslan_K - ваш ответ решил проблему, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, в качестве ответа, будет полезно для других участников.